# Montgomery Curve Point Multiplication in Projective Coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, montgomery-multiplication

Is the result of 4G the same when calculated as 3G + 1G or 2G + 2G in projective coordinates? Considering a curve like (y^2 = x^3 + 10x^2 + x (mod 83)) with a Generator point G = (3, 28) in affine coordinates, or (3:28:1) in projective coordinates, the calculations indicate that 2G = (64:Y-coordinate:65) and 3G = (25:Y-coordinate:9). However, for 4G, when calculated as:

First: 2G + 2G, you obtain (64:Y-coordinate:65) + (64:Y-coordinate:65) = (41:Y-coordinate:26),

Second: and when calculated as 3G + 1G, you get (25:Y-coordinate:9) + (3:28:1) = (77:Y-coordinate:48).

The first calculation correct because the x-coordinates match when converted back to affine coordinates. But there always seems to be a difference between 4G=2G+2G and 4G=3G+1G. Why is that?

Note that I wrote Y-coordinate based on how points are represented in projective coordinates and since it wasn't utilized in the subsequent computations, I didn’t mention its value and I just wrote Y-coordinate instead.
I will detail all the calculations to clarify the challenges encountered in this curve and others in Montgomery curves:
As I mentioned that I am sure that 2G = (64:Y:65) and 3G (25:Y:9). let’s start with 4G = 2G + 2G utilizing the point doubling mathematical laws and of curse all the calculations is made under (mod 83) :

4G = 2G + 2G = (64:Y:65) + (64:Y:65)

4XZ = (X+Z)^2 –(X-Z)^2 = (64+65)^2 – (64-65)^2 = 40

X_result = (X+Z)^2 * (X-Z)^2 = (64+65)^2 * (64-65)^2 = 41

Z_result = 4XZ * ((X-Z)^2 + (A+2/4)*4XZ) = 40 * ((64-65)^2 + (10+2/4) * 40) = 26

So 4G in this scenario is (41:Y:26) or (41:26) as excluding Y representation.

but when we calculate 4G = 3G + 1G = (25:Y:9)+(3:28:1) utilizing the point adding mathematical laws, we get the following:

X_result = Z * ((X2-Z2)(X1+Z1)+(X2+Z2)(X1-Z1))^2 = 1*((3-1)(25+9)+(3+1)(25-9))^2 = (2*34 + 4*16)^2 = 77

Z_result = X * ((X2-Z2)(X1+Z1)-(X2+Z2)(X1-Z1))^2 = 3 * ((3-1)(25+9) - (3+1)(25-9))^2 = 3 * (2*34 – 4*16)^2 = 48

As shown and in this scenario 4G = (77:Y:48) or (77:48)

Comment: Why do you write `Y-coordinate` and why do you omit $Z$ in projective coordinates? $(X:Y:Z)$ This tells the projective coordinate used ( equivalence relation). Where are the details of your calculations? Probably $Z$ becomes larger than `1` and you omit to normalize?

Comment: @kelalaka , what do you mean by (Probably  Z  becomes larger than 1 and you omit to normalize?) because in addition law the X3 it always multiplied by Z-coordinate of the generator point and it is equal to 1 always. Right ? or there is something I misunderstood ?

Comment: In the Q there is (A+2/4) where there should be ((A+2)/4), and then the doubling method in the Q matches [this](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html#doubling-dbl-1987-m-2). When I compute 2*(3:28:1) then 4*(3:28:1) in this way I get (64:Y:65) and (41:Y:26) like in the Q. What is the origin and conditions of application of the formula used to compute 4G = 3G + 1G ? I think I recognize the formula for (2n+1)G as a function of nG, (n+1)G, and G, as in the bottom of the first page of [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/293.pdf), but how would that allow to compute 4G?

Comment: @fgrieu , I didn't get what do you mean by(I think I recognize the formula for (2n+1)G as a function of nG, (n+1)G, and G, as ...).
I made my calculations according to the code exists in page 8 of [https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#page-4] which based on the formula in the
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Montgomery_arithmetic].
I don't face any problem with doubling calculations, so I got the correct answers when I calculate 2G = G+G, 4G =(2G+2G), 8G=(4G+4G), ... but I am facing the problem in Adding operation 4G=3G+1, 5G=4G+1,... but I didn't face it with 3G=2G+G

Comment: I think (not sure) that the formula for addition that you are using has preconditions that are met in the case of [that](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#page-9) algorithm, but not in your use to compute 3G+G. This formula works when adding (n+1)G and nG knowing G, perhaps more generally to add P and Q knowing P-Q, but I do not see that we are in this case, at least when you take X=3.

Comment: As I know, P-Q is always equal to the Generator point, So there is no need to calculate it. Can you please explain me simply what do you mean by ( adding (n+1)G and nG knowing G) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Montgomery Curve $y^2\equiv x^3+10x^2+x\pmod{83}$ with $G$ having $(x,y)=(3,28)$, and using projective coordinates $(X,Y,Z)$ defined by $x\,Z=X$ and $y\,Z=Y$, the question is correctly stating that $(X,Z)$ is $(3,1)$ for $G$, is $(64,65)$ for $2G$, and is $(25,9)$ for $3G$.

The question computes $4G$ by doubling $2G$ using [these](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html#doubling-dbl-1987-m-2) doubling formulas, correctly yielding that $(X,Z)$ is $(41,26)$ for $2(2G)=4G$.

The question then attempts an alternate computation of $4G$ as $3G+G$ using essentially [these](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html#diffadd-dadd-1987-m) addition formulas (with the indexes changed). The formulas compute $(X,Z)$ for $P+Q$ knowing $(X,Z)$ for $P$, $Q$, and $P-Q$, respectively noted (X1, Z1), (X2, Z2), and (X, Z) in the question.

The mistake made is using the wrong $(X,Z)$ for $P-Q$: that should be $(64,65)$ for $2G=3G-G$, not $(3,1)$ for $G$. The cause of the mistake is that the formula is most often used in the Montgomery ladder, where the two operands are $(n+1)G$ and $nG$ (within order), thus $P-Q$ is $G$ (within sign, which does not change the $(X,Z)$ coordinates).

With this correction we get that $(X,Z)$ for $3G+G$ is $(25,28)$, which as expected is equivalent to $(X,Z)$ for $2(2G)$ of $(41,26)$, since $25⋅26\equiv28⋅41\pmod{83}$.

Comment: You accurately pointed out the mistake I made. I'm very grateful for your help, thank you so much for assisting me.

Comment: @NawrasHussein: this has been useful to me too: I now better understand the so-called differential addition on Montgomery curve.

Comment: So does this what differential addition on Montgomery curve means? Or does it have another meaning?

Comment: @NawrasHussein: My new understanding of differential addition on Montgomery curve is that it computes on (X,Z) coordinates, getting these for P+Q knowing these for P, Q, and P-Q. My former understanding was restricted to the context of computing multiples of G per the Montgomery ladder, which happens to keep (X,Z) for P-Q to the same (X,1) as for G all along.